# Remoting with delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, remoting

in one of our applications we have an (existing) interface like this:

```
public interface INotify
{
  void RegisterNotification(Action<int, string> notification);
}
```

Now we want to implement a "remoting layer" using IpcChannels for objects implementing this interface.
I read many articles regarding remoting, delegates and events, but can´t get a test scenario working. Most examples use events directly implemented in the server class, not delegates in arguments.
Does someone know a working example or give me a hint?

**Made it** by creating an "EventSink" and re-creating the delegate using Expression lambdas. Seems a bit complicated but working...

Comment: You have in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel(v=vs.110).aspx) some examples, but why you need to use IPC?

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
We need to use remoting and IPC because we want to use the INativeHandleContract for remotely-created wpf controls that shall be used in the application (AddIn mechanism).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EventSink:

```
public class GenericEventSink : MarshalByRefObject
{
  public event GenericDelegate MessageReceived;

  public Type OriginalType { get; }

  public GenericEventSink(Delegate original)
  {
    OriginalType = original.GetType();
    MessageReceived += objects =>
    {
      try
      {
        return original.DynamicInvoke(objects);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        return null;
      }
    };
  }

  public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
  {
    return null;
  }

  public object OnMessageReceived0()
  {
    return MessageReceived?.Invoke();
  }
  public object OnMessageReceived1(object o1)
  {
    return MessageReceived?.Invoke(o1);
  }
  public object OnMessageReceived2(object o1, object o2)
  {
    return MessageReceived?.Invoke(o1, o2);
  }
  public object OnMessageReceived3(object o1, object o2, object o3)
  {
    return MessageReceived?.Invoke(o1, o2, o3);
  }
}
```

...and the method to re-create the delegate to be invoked:

```
private object UnmarshalDelegate(GenericEventSink generic)
{
  var pars = generic.OriginalType.GenericTypeArguments.Select(Expression.Parameter).ToArray();

  // create the call
  var method = generic.GetType().GetMethod("OnMessageReceived" + pars.Length);
  var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(generic), method, pars.Select(p => Expression.Convert(p, typeof(object))));
  return Expression.Lambda(generic.OriginalType, call, pars).Compile();
}
```